# Get quickly http response code of a Url

Tags: php, curl

I know it is very easy to get http response code like we may use get_headers() function or we can also use cURL but I have 3 millions url.

So please show me the way how can I get status of each url quickly.

Because in current scenario each url is taking approx 1 sec, then you may calculate how much time it would take to finish.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("2.6MMURL-10-14.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
$i = 1;
//echo '<pre>';
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

       //print_r($data[0]);
       $result = getStatus($data[0]);
       echo  $result."<br />";
      // print_r($result); 
       if($i == 16)
       {
       echo $i;
       //appendToCsv($result);

       //exit;
       }

       $i++;
    }


    fclose($handle);
}
exit;
function getStatus($fileSource) {
//$fileSource = "www.google.com";
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $ch = curl_init($fileSource);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');         
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  $last_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  //print_r($response); exit;
  preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);
  $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  curl_close($ch);
  //!empty($matches[1]) ? $redirect = trim($matches[1][0]) : $redirect = 'No redirect found';
  $redirect = trim($matches[1][0]);
$time.= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$array = "$fileSource, $retcode, $trim($matches[1][0], $time";
return $array;
    //print_r($last_url); exit;

    //curl_close($ch);
    }

function appendToCsv($data) {
    header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');


$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ( $data as $line ) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);

}
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: start running requests in parallel. unless you're doing this on a 300 baud dialup line, there's very little you can do to speed up the network component. so either run more requests in parallel (easyish), or find some way to cut down the per-request time (hard/impossible).

Comment: use wget, something like this - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61132/how-do-i-use-wget-with-a-list-of-urls-and-their-corresponding-output-files

Comment: I have added code @ Mr. Concolato

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to run multiple HEAD HTTP requests in parallel using **curl_multi_exec**. HEAD requests are identical to GET but without the response body. It will save you some bandwidth/time as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use pcntl_fork()

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php